# Decreasing sequence of real numbers with zero limit imply the limit of the ratio exists.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given a decreasing sequence ($x_n$) in $\mathbb R$ such that $\lim x_n=0$, does it follow that $\lim\left(\frac{|x_{{n+1}}|}{|x_n|}\right)$ exist?

Why I ask is that I want to show that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_{n}z^n$, $z\in\mathbb C$ has radius of convergence $\rho\ge 1 $

If this the above limit does exists than we would have $1\le \frac{|x_{n}|}{|x_{n+1}|}$ since ${x_n}$ is decreasing and the result should follow.

Comment: No. $x_{2n} = x_{2n+1} = 2^{-n}$.

Comment: For what you want to show, ise the Root Test, although a properly formulated Ratio Test will work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: What do you mean? I thought the easiest way to show convergence of a power series is via comparing with the appropriate geometric series?

Comment: Yes, that will do it. You are using the wrong ratio from my point of view, it should be $\frac{x_{n+1}|z|}{x_n}$. This is $\lt 1$ if $|z|\lt 1$. That's what I meant by properly formulated Ratio Test.

Answer (score 0):

Any bounded sequence, or any sequence of polynomial growth (like $x_n = n^5 -5n^3$ for example) will give a radius of convergence $\ge 1.$ As for the ratios $x_{n+1}/x_n$ of a decreasing positive sequence $x_n \to 0,$ they can be dense in $[0,1].$

Comment: So it's not necessarily the case that limit of the ratio will exist under these conditions? Rather it only can exist?

Comment: Yes, forget about a limit, those ratios can be all over the place